# Converting to numpy array makes tensorflow gradient "None"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I tried to train my TensorFlow 2.0 model.
However, gradients appear to None when converted to Numpy array.
Why is it happening?

```
#somelist: the list that contains the floating point numbers

a = tf.reduce_sum(np.asarray(somelist))

b = tf.reduce_sum(np.array(somelist))

c = tf.reduce_sum(somelist)
```

1) `tape.gradient(a, model.trainable_variables)`
outputs "None"

2) `tape.gradient(b, model.trainable_variables)`
outputs "None"

3) `tape.gradient(c, model.trainable_variables)`
outputs the tensors of gradients

Comment: You have no trainable variables `--->` No gradients

Comment: Because TF is TF and numpy is numpy. TF has no idea how to compute gradients for numpy arrays so they come out as `None`.